# How to configure pre-build action in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How can i configure Eclipse Oxygen (in C++ project if that matters) to run a script each time i want to build the program (so the script runs first and only then the program is built and run)?

Comment: See Eclipse help: _[Non-Ant project builders](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-96_non_ant_pjs.htm)_

Answer (score 0):

You can always replace the default build command with a custom script:

1. Go into the `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build`;
2. Uncheck `Use default build command` and insert your own, e.g.:
   `${workspace_loc:/YOUR_PROJ/build.sh}`

Answer (score 0):

I found this alternative solution, which seems to me more natural to the one proposed by biscuitoman:

1. Go to `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings` and select `Build Steps` tab.
   Add your custom command to `Pre-build steps`.

[Here](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_build_settings_steps.htm) is the documentation from eclipse.